# A New Riddle From The Bleaker Gap

Tags: riddle

I come from the hell as you know, but the nun gave birth to me.

I can be big or small.

I am at the unlucky position.

When two of me are here, you see envy.

I can say how free it is, or maybe, how frequent it is.

Sometimes, I just pass by, as a little mystery, indifferent to anything that tries to attract me.

Often, I am ytisned; or, I may be the right proportion of poison.

Who/what am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am still working out some details but I think you are probably

> the Greek letter nu.

"A New Riddle"

> "New" and "nu" sound alike.

I come from the hell as you know

> Dunno what that's about. ... Ah, it turns out to be a pun on "Hellas" = Greece, as revealed by Ankoganit in comments.

but the nun gave birth to me

> "Nun" is the name of the letter of semitic abjads (e.g., Phoenician) corresponding to "N", and Greek nu is derived from it. (As is our letter N.)

I can be big or small.

> The Greek alphabet, like ours, has upper and lower cases.

I am at the unlucky position.

> Thirteenth letter of the Greek alphabet.

When two of me are here, you see envy.

> I think "envy" = "NV" here. Perhaps what we have is one capital and one lowercase nu; a capital nu looks like a latin N but a lowercase nu looks more like a latin v.

I can say how free it is, or maybe, how frequent it is.

> In statistics nu denotes number of degrees of freedom; in physics, frequency.

Sometimes, I just pass by, as a little mystery, indifferent to anything that tries to attract me.

> Nu is the symbol used for neutrinos, whose interactions with other particles are notoriously weak.

Often, I am ytisned;

> Nu is the usual symbol for "specific volume", which equals the reciprocal of density.

or, I may be the right proportion of poison.

> I fear this is a reference to "*Poisson*'s ratio".

Comment: "I come from the Hellas, you know." And there's the bleaker gap...

Comment: Oh, I do hope not :-).

Comment: Oh, wait, it's your puzzle.

Comment: (Sorry about that. I thought that was merely a suggestion from another reader rather than a revelation from the actual puzzle author. For the avoidance of doubt, that's "hope not" as in "it would be a really groanworthy pun" rather than a serious complaint that it mars the puzzle.)

Comment: It's Okay.. :-) One of the reasons for the revelation is that it's a weird pun.